# Getting error while Custom Annotation using values from properties file - Syntax error on token ")", default expected after this token

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, annotations

i am creating a Custom Annotation as below,

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@CrossOrigin
public @interface CrossOriginsList {

    @Value("#{'${allowed.origins}'.split(',')}")
    //public static final List<String> rawOrigins;
    public static final String[] rawOrigins = ProcessOrigins.getOrigin();
    
    public String[] crossOrigins() default {
        int size = rawOrigins.size();
        String[] originArray = new String[size];
        return rawOrigins.toArray(originArray);            
    };   
}
```

In my application.properties i have defined  as below,

```
allowed.origins=http://localhost:8080,http://localhost:4200
```

But getting compiler error,

```
Syntax error on token ")", default expected after this token
```

Getting error at below line in Eclipse,

```
public String[] crossOrigins() default {
```

How to resolve this error ?

**EDIT**
Below is the Processor class,

```
public class ProcessOrigins {

    @Value("#{'${allowed.origins}'.split(',')}")
    public static List<String> rawOrigins; 
    
    public static String[] getOrigin() {
        int size = rawOrigins.size();
        String[] originArray = new String[size];
        return rawOrigins.toArray(originArray);
    }   
}
```

Comment: well the curly brackets after the default identifier are not code brackets but static array initialization brackets. So you could do something like: `public String[] crossOrigins() default {"string1","string2"};`. Also you need to initialize rawOrigins in some way.

Comment: So i would have to hardcode the values in that case ?. cant i read it from properties file ?

Comment: Not inside the interface class. You need a processor class which handles the logic. There you can inject your `rawOrigins` and treat them as default values if for example the `crossOrigins` are empty.

Comment: I crated a Processor class and got the values from appln.props and assigned to rawOrigins of Annotation. But i am not able to use the rawOrigins in the return of the crossOrigins as it says it needs a constant Expression

Comment: The `rawOrigins` List should not be part of the annotation, since it is nothing you want to set when annotating something, but something you want to configure in your properties. So you should make `rawOrigins` part of your Processor and then implement logic there, e.g. if the `crossOrigins` are empty use `rawOrigins`instead, or whatever you want to do there. Since i don't know your processor code, this is up to you.

Comment: Updated the Question...Added the Processor class. Had used a String[] in Annoation as public static final String[] rawOrigins = ProcessOrigins.getOrigin();                                  Also how would write the code that if crossOrigins are empty use rawOriginsinstead ? I am not sure how to write this part of code.

Comment: What I actually meant with processor class is the code where you do something with the methods, that you annotated with your `CrossOriginsList`. What are you using this annotation for?

Comment: You can not specify a code block after `default` in an annotation. Besides that, the code makes no sense. You’re trying to call `size()` and `toArray(…)` on a variable that is already referencing an array. Anyway, you can only specify compile-time constants after `default`. To change the behavior of the code that uses the annotation, i.e. to use a certain runtime value array when the annotation array is empty, just change that code.